# Why does Application created twice?

Tags: android

My application is doing quite a bit of initialization in the `Application::onCreate()` method, and I have a check that will throw an exception if it is called twice.

However, in some specific circumstance, the `Application::onCreate()` gets called twice. I added the following `Log` statement in `onCreate()`: (`instance` is a static variable)

```
Log.i(TAG, "Application::ctor, this=" + this + " instance=" + instance + " pid="
            + android.os.Process.myPid());
```

I got two logs (normally, `instance == null`):

```
09-20 19:14:42.151 {main} [INFO] [Application] Application::ctor, this=com.shawnma.MyApplication@428886b0 instance=null pid=10741
09-20 19:14:50.116 {main} [INFO] [Application] Application::ctor, this=com.shawnma.MyApplication@42923e00 instance=com.shawnma.MyApplication@428886b0 pid=10741
```

In this case, I returned from the `onCreate()` method - it won't hurt since everything should always be in memory. However, another exception shows immediately after that from Android system:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innopath.mobilemd/com.innopath.mobilemd.ui.LauncherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:100)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:51)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2019)
            ... 11 more
```

It seems the second `Application` creation is triggered by an `ALARM_MANAGER` wake up. But still, the first creation of the app should have been done and saved in a memory location?

Comment: Where do you do your deinitialization?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but similar bug is described here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56296

Comment: I've run into the same problem (`Application.onCreate()` called twice) on a couple of user devices in Production. How did you determine that it was triggered by `ALARM_MANAGER`? My app doesn't use alarms, so it might have a different cause in my case.

Comment: Does you found a cause of this behaviour? Or may be some kind of solution to fix it?

Answer (score -3):

Check if there is another process specified in your AndroidManifest. If you app contains two processes that use the same Application, the the `onCreate` method in Application will be invoked twice.

Comment: This isn't the case because he's using a static `instance` variable to track the multiple calls to `Application.onCreate()`. Static variables aren't shared across processes.

Comment: Also note that `pid` is the same in each of his log messages.